# Page Not Found - how to find current path is valid in Django URL's?

Tags: django, url, django-urls

Please Note I gone through all answer i didnt found solution,

I am getting this error, i know current URL `asdf` is not presented in urls.py my question i want to check whether my current path is in urls or not?

i tried `path == reverse('some_view')` but i need existing specific view to test. but i dont have anything except current path.

here is the not found error,

> Page not found (404)
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8002/asdf/

here i want to redirect if URL is not present in urls.py how to do this?

Comment: If you need custom 404 handler, you need set `DEBUG=False` and add `handler404 = 'mysite.views.my_view'` to the urls.py, see details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a middleware is the answer.
Something like this:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve, Resolver404


class CheckURLExists(object):  

    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            resolve(url)
        except Resolver404:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('some url')
```

then in the settings add the middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'middlewares.redirects.CheckURLExists,
]
```

A middleware allows you to intercept any request, and do whatever you wants.

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is try to resolve your test url and if you encounter a 404 you can redirect it.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve, Resolver404

    .....   
    try:
       return bool(resolve(url))
    except Resolver404:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('some url')
```

Answer (score 0):

In settings.py activate your middleware.

In middleware.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class MyMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        if response.status_code == 404:
            return redirect('someurl') 
        else:
            return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        pass
```